# Java System.getProperty("user.home")

Tags: java, system

In this line of code, I am using the `getProperty` method :

```java
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("~/4413/ctrl/geo.txt".replaceFirst("^~", System.getProperty("user.home")), "UTF-8");
```

The result is `C:UsersKamel\4413\ctrl\geo.txt` which not exactly what I want as long as some `\` separators are missing at the begining.

Is there anything I can add so that the path becomes correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote `System.getProperty("user.home")`:

```
Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getProperty("user.home"))
```

The issue is that both parameters of `replaceFirst` treat characters in special ways, because you are dealing with regular expressions, not literal strings.

Comment: Or as long as we can assume that `~` may only appear *at start of the path* with `.replace("~", System.getProperty("user.home"))` we don't need to worry about regex syntax at all.

Comment: @Pshemo or something using `startsWith` and `substring`.